# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "taskname": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Hello i am trying to test my Database with a test app but it seems there is something wrong with my SQL  cause i get an error while compiling

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "taskname": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tasks(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT taskname TEXT taskdescription TEXT );
```

Anyone know how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is missing a comma between `AUTOINCREMENT` and `taskname`. Column definitions in a `CREATE TABLE` statement are comma-delimited.